# Кастомный адаптер. Или текст или изображение

Tags: java, android, adapter

Локальная база данных имеет структуру: поле с текстом и цифровое поле. Если во втором поле число 2, значит первое поле содержит ссылку на изображение, иначе первое поле содержит сообщение.

Пытаюсь вывести это в кастомный адаптер следующим способом:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        NotesSaveData chatMessageObj = getItem(position);
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.castom_notes_list, parent, false);
        }
        singleMessageContainer = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);

        chatText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.data);
       imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewList);
       // chatName.setText(chatMessageObj.name);

        if (chatMessageObj.type==1) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            chatText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            chatText.setText(chatMessageObj.message);
        }else if (chatMessageObj.type ==2){
chatText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  File file = new File(chatMessageObj.message);
              Glide
                      .with(row)
                    .load(file)
                  .into(imageView);
        }
        return row;
    }
```

То есть, в зависимости от содержания, я меняю видимость вью-элементов. В принципе, такая схема работает, но при скроллинге размеры изображений скачут, иногда изображения путаются местами, размеры полей подстраиваются под размер изображения в не зависимости от содержимого, да и вообще мне кажется, что это костыль.

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать такую задачу?

Comment: "скачущие" и подстраивающиеся размеры - это скорее всего проблемы разметки айтема - добавьте ее в вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом). Путаются местами скорее всего из-за того, что на получение изображения требуется некоторое время, в то время, как адаптер переиспользует айтемы, то есть в них остается то, что было в них ранее, в других позициях - решить можно или плейсхолдером, раз уж вы используете Glide или принудительной очисткой ImageView **перед получением** в него картинки

Comment: В целом я решил проблему путем масштабирования изображений и увеличением сжатия картинок, но при быстром скролинге лист вью притормаживает